# How to save image using php and can retrieve using json

Tags: php, android

How can I retrieve the image from database using json encode to android studio?
I don't know if it is the correct format for saving the image that can retrieve using android.

```
    $qrlink = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=1"
    $qrimage = addslashes(file_get_contents($qrlink));
```

Using `addslashes(file_get_contents())`, I can retrieve this image using html `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode()`

But in `json_encode` and `decode` to android studio is not working.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

What is the best way to save the image that can retrieve/fetch using json_encode response w/ android studio?